# getting previous element's html in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs that all have class "leftNav".  When a user clicks some arrow (previous), i want to grab the previous div and mark it. Using .prev('.leftNav')  or .prevAll('.leftNav') doesnt seem to work.  If user is currently on 15 and clicks previous, I want the html from 14.

```js
$('.lastProduct').click(function() {
    $('.leftNav').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        var html = $(this).prevAll().html();
        //Also tried - var html = $(this).prev().html();
        //Also tried - var html = $(this).prev('.lastNav').html();
        //Also tried - var html = $(this).prevAll('.lastNav').html();
        alert(html);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='lastNav' id='13'>13</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='lastNav' id='14'>14</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='lastNav selected' id='15'>15</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='lastNav' id='16'>16</div>
</div>


<input type='button' class='lastProduct' value='Previous'>
```

all of those attempts result in "undefined"

What am I missing?

Comment: There's no class called `leftNav` in the markup shown...

Comment: `.click()` is [Deprecated](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/issues/343) use `.on()` instead.  [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) -- `$( ".lastProduct" ).on( "click", function(){` This is not your issue .. Just friendly advice ..

Comment: @David  typo, i meant lastNav

Comment: apart from the `leftNav` issue prev won't work becuase the last nav elements don't have siblings - you would needt to do `.parent().prev()`

Comment: @bart2puck: When you corrected this typo in your code, did you re-test?  Have you noticed the console error this code is producing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the mismatch of the `leftNav` and `lastNav` classes in your code is just a typo, then you don't need an `each()` loop here.

You can directly select the `.selected` instance and traverse the DOM to find the parent `.row` using `closest()`. From there you can use `prev()` and `find()` to target the relevant `.lastNav` element before updating the classes on each of them.

```js
$('.lastProduct').on('click', function() {
  const $current = $('.leftNav.selected');
  const $row = $current.closest('.row');
  const $prev = $row.prev().find('.leftNav');

  if ($prev.length) {
    $current.removeClass('selected');
    $prev.addClass('selected');
    
    const prevText = $prev.text();
    console.log(prevText);
  }
})
```

```css
.selected {
  color: #C00;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="leftNav" id="13">13</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="leftNav" id="14">14</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="leftNav selected" id="15">15</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="leftNav" id="16">16</div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="lastProduct">Previous</button>
```